# Using C programming, Implement a Least Recently Used (LRU) algorithm using a proper data structure such as linked list or bitmap or hash table

Tags: c

I am trying to place my LRU inside a data structure and print out the number of read and write from the memory, but I am getting stuck with an error message.

This is the error message

```
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c: In function 'newQNode':
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:39:8: error: redefinition of 'temp'
   39 | QNode* temp = (QNode*)malloc(sizeof(QNode));
      |        ^~~~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:35:8: note: previous definition of 'temp' was here
   35 | QNode* temp = (QNode*)malloc(sizeof(QNode));
      |        ^~~~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c: At top level:
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:139:24: error: 'pageNumber' undeclared here (not in a function)
  139 | QNode* temp = newQNode(pageNumber);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:141:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
  141 |     temp->next = queue->front;
      |         ^~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:143:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'if'
  143 | if (isQueueEmpty(queue))
      | ^~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:147:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'else'
  147 |     else // Else change the front
      |     ^~~~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:159:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
  159 |     hash->array[pageNumber] = temp;
      |         ^~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:163:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
  163 |     queue->count++;
      |          ^~
/tmp/KOJ9w6aX4a.c:165:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
  165 | }
      | ^
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct QNode {
    struct QNode *prev, *next;
    unsigned pageNumber; // the page number stored in this QNode
} QNode;

typedef struct Queue {
    unsigned count; // Number of filled frames
    unsigned numberOfFrames; // total number of frames
    QNode *front, *rear;
} Queue;

typedef struct Hash {
    int capacity; // how many pages can be there
    QNode** array; // an array of queue nodes
} Hash;

QNode* newQNode(unsigned pageNumber)
{
    QNode* temp = (QNode*)malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    temp->pageNumber = pageNumber;
    QNode* temp = (QNode*)malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    temp->pageNumber = pageNumber;
    temp->prev = temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

Queue* createQueue(int numberOfFrames)
{
    Queue* queue = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    queue->count = 0;
    queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    queue->numberOfFrames = numberOfFrames;
    return queue;
}

Hash* createHash(int capacity)
{
    Hash* hash = (Hash*)malloc(sizeof(Hash));
    hash->capacity = capacity;
    hash->array = (QNode**)malloc(hash->capacity * sizeof(QNode*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < hash->capacity; ++i)
        hash->array[i] = NULL;
    return hash;
}

int AreAllFramesFull(Queue* queue)
{
    return queue->count == queue->numberOfFrames;
}

int isQueueEmpty(Queue* queue)
{
    return queue->rear == NULL;
}

void deQueue(Queue* queue)
{
    if (isQueueEmpty(queue))
        return;
    if (queue->front == queue->rear)
        queue->front = NULL;
    QNode* temp = queue->rear;
    queue->rear = queue->rear->prev;
    if (queue->rear)
        queue->rear->next = NULL;
    free(temp);
    queue->count--;
}

void Enqueue(Queue* queue, Hash* hash, unsigned pageNumber)
{
    if (AreAllFramesFull(queue))
        hash->array[queue->rear->pageNumber] = NULL;
    deQueue(queue);
}

QNode* temp = newQNode(pageNumber);
temp->next = queue->front;

if (isQueueEmpty(queue))
    queue->rear = queue->front = temp;

else // Else change the front
{
    queue->front->prev = temp;
    queue->front = temp;
}

// Add page entry to hash also
hash->array[pageNumber] = temp;

// increment number of full frames
queue->count++;

}

// This function is called when a page with given 'pageNumber' is referenced
// from cache (or memory). There are two cases:
// 1. Frame is not there in memory, we bring it in memory and add to the front
// of queue
// 2. Frame is there in memory, we move the frame to front of queue
void ReferencePage(Queue* queue, Hash* hash, unsigned pageNumber)
{
    QNode* reqPage = hash->array[pageNumber];
    // the page is not in cache, bring it
    if (reqPage == NULL)
        Enqueue(queue, hash, pageNumber);
    // page is there and not at front, change pointer
    else if (reqPage != queue->front) {

        // Unlink rquested page from its current location
        // in queue.
        reqPage->prev->next = reqPage->next;
        if (reqPage->next)
            reqPage->next->prev = reqPage->prev;

        // If the requested page is rear, then change rear
        // as this node will be moved to front
        if (reqPage == queue->rear) {
            queue->rear = reqPage->prev;
            queue->rear->next = NULL;
        }

        // Put the requested page before current front
        reqPage->next = queue->front;
        reqPage->prev = NULL;

        // Change prev of current front
        reqPage->next->prev = reqPage;

        // Change front to the requested page
        queue->front = reqPage;
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    // Let cache can hold 4 pages
    Queue* q = createQueue(4);

    // Let 10 different pages can be requested (pages to be
    // referenced are numbered from 0 to 9
    Hash* hash = createHash(10);

    // Let us refer pages 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 1);
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 2);
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 3);
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 1);
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 4);
    ReferencePage(q, hash, 5);

    // Let us print cache frames after the above referenced pages
    printf("%d ", q->front->pageNumber);
    printf("%d ", q->front->next->pageNumber);
    printf("%d ", q->front->next->next->pageNumber);
    printf("%d ", q->front->next->next->next->pageNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly as the error message says you redefine `temp` twice in `newQNode`, looks like you have 2 lines duplicated in that function

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.